# How to generate Analog Signal (Voice) to the microphone

Tags: programming, analogread, arduino-pro-mini, adc, sound

I have question about microphone and generating sound signal. I have microphone in my intercom at home. It is simple analog microphone, not digital.

What I want is to connect arduino analog output to the microphone and generate some signal that will be heard like a voice at least few words.

Is it possible to do this ? Or it would be quite hard ?

Please suggest the easiest way to implement this.

Comment: This might help https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleAudioPlayer

Comment: It will be impossible to "generate some signal that will be heard like a voice" using an Uno - or perhaps any Arduino. Playing a pre-recorded track is possible, as linked in a previous comment, but you will need a board with a digital to analogue convertor built in, like a Due.